# Integral piecewise function matlab

Tags: matlab, integral, piecewise

I am trying to integrate a function `F` which is defined as:

```
function F        
    x = -3:0.1:3;
    F = zeros(1, length(x));
    for i = 1:length(x)
        if (1.4<= x(i)) && (x(i) <= 1.6)
            F(i) = x(i).^2;
        else
            F(i) = 2;
        end
    end 
end
```

but the `integral` function gives me an error saying that there are too many arguments. I think the problem that the function is defined as a points?

Comment: Please, for the shake of all of us, indent that code properly. Also, show us the code that errors. You are esentially not understanding how to call integral. A function is something of the form `f(x)`, your F has not inputs. You should not define `x`, else `F` is an array, not a function.

Comment: The problem is with the line where you call the `integral` function, show us *that* line of your code too!

Comment: I call the int function like 

integral(F,0,1)
and i get the error 
Error using F
Too many output arguments.

as you said i think my function F is an array,if that the problem  so how could I define F as a function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your function, is that `integral` has no way to pass the arguments you supply to your function `F`. The function doesn't know that it can just pull certain elements from the vector you created. If you rewrite your function such that for an input (or x value), the output of `F` is returned, then `integral` will work as you need given two values to integrate between.